# Factorising Iterated Integrals

Tags: integration

I've been doing a bunch of homework about iterated double and triple integrals recently and a bunch of solutions seem to skip steps and use shortcuts that everyone seems to know, but no one seems to say, mainly:
$\iint g(x)\cdot h(y)\,dx\,dy=\int g(x)\,dx\,\cdot\,\int h(y)\,dy$

I've searched for ages, but I've not been able to find anything about any such rule (although I've undoubtedly missed something). It works if they're definite integrals and $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ are integrable, but are there major exceptions to this or something else that stops this from being a rule or best practice? Or maybe is it just wrong? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that $h(y)$ is a constant (relative to $x$), so you can pull it through the $\mathrm{d}x$-integral: $$\int g(x) h(y) \, \mathrm{d}x =  h(y) \Big(\int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\Big).$$ $\int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is a constant, so you can pull it through the $\mathrm{d}y$-integral: $$\int h(y) \Big(\int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\Big) \, \mathrm{d}y = \Big( \int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \Big) \int h(y) \, \mathrm{d}y.$$ This is rigorous as long as both $\int g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and $\int h(y) \, \mathrm{d}y$ exist in whatever since you need them to.